# Writing full 100+ lines of html to a file with php

Tags: php, html, function, fwrite

I have a system set up where, when the user registers, it creates a custom directory for them and then inside that directory it creates a file called `index.html`. I would like to write an entire HTML page of 100+ lines to that file. I was using `fopen() fwrite($filepath, 'content');`, but there are escape characters like `''` and `""` that mess up the PHP function.

Is there a better way to write large content to these files, or should I just have the file saved somewhere on my webserver and then just transfer it to each new registered user?

Comment: `that mess up the php function`.  What are you doing with the text to allow this to happen?

Comment: If those quotes mess up the function, that means they're hard-coded in somewhere, so if you were to write `fwrite($fh, '"someone"');` you're fine, as you would be when writing `fwrite($fh, "it's Monty Python's Flying circus");` because the quotes inside the string aren't the quotes that delimit the string constant. Just escape the quotes you're using as delimiters (`fwirte($fh, 'Single quotes aren\'t an issue when using "\\"');` or check the [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/heredoc)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem He would need to take non-UTF8 encoded html files into consideration before compiling it to PHP, personally i'd just base64 the whole file as a quick and dirty solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have the file on disk, and it will not change for each user, then you should copy the file.

It is a waste of resources to read and then write the file with PHP..

[PHP Manual - copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `htmlentities($var);`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: won't work, as the html gets broken. Only of use if you want to show the characters as-is, and not let them be interpreted by the browser or any other interpreter

Answer (score 0):

Well that means that where you say 'content' you have a hard coded html file in your script itself. It would be easier to just save a standard html file somewhere on the webserver and to something like this:

```
file_put_contents('/path/to/user/file', file_get_contents('/path/to/standard/index.html'));
```

Easier to maintain (no html in your code, but just in a testable html file) and no worries about escaping characters. Easy does it :)

**Edit**

Someone smarter than me proposed to just copy the file. Which is ofcourse a lot more sensible to do than reading and writing contents...